# Titanium stuck on splash when app taken in background

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Here is [video](https://youtu.be/INpb-3M66U4?t=1m55s) of the problem.

When I run the app first time, works perfectly. 
Then I press back button. 
When I try to open the app once again, stuck on splash.

Comment: That's weird. What SDK are you using? Are you using any modules? Can I see your index.js or app.js?

Comment: @Shawn as you can see from the vide I don't use any module. This is start code from titanium.

Comment: I use the latest version 5.5.0 but it happens in all versions.

Comment: I can reproduce it. Didn't see this issue before. Could be a valid bug starting 5.4.0 or 5.5.0. Jira ticket filed here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4503

Answer (score 1):

I'm also seeing this issue and saw that this issue is already reported: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23901 and there are pull request already to fix it.

Have a look at this comment over here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23901?focusedCommentId=396701&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-396701
there is a comparison of the versions and it looks like that 5.3.0 should be fine at the moment.

Comment: Just a short update: PR has been merged into master and 6.0.x

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on Android, you could find some useful informations in  [Titanium.Android.Activity](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity) API docs, "Handling Application Restarts"